How to remove .blend thumbnail previews
I am used to organizing by name and the thumbnails are distracting and confusing me in the file explorer.
How do I set the .blend and .blend1 files to only show blender icon on them instead of the preview?

See if setting 'File Preview Type' to 'None' in File  > Edit > Preferences > Save & Load > Blend Files stops them being created. This is the section in the Blender manual. I guess you'd have to purge any preview files from your OS for ones already created but that's not really a Blender problem.
